# Launching a Python loop & getting back data

Tags: python, c++

I have a C++ program and a Python script (**loop.py**).

The `main` function of **loop.py** generates random numbers.

The C++ program uses the Python C API to call the `main` function of **loop.py**. I encapsulated the Python code in a **PythonWrapper** static class.

This works without problem.
But now, I would like to retrieve the random numbers generated by **loop.py**.

I tried to create a `getData` function in **loop.py** and to call it in another thread of the C++ program, after launching the `main` function. But I got multiple errors (segmentation fault,...)

I don't understand if these problems are related to the fact that I try to access the same Python module, or the same variable, and I don't know how to resolve them.
I also thought of calling a C++ function from the Python script to send the numbers, but I cannot find a way to do this properly.

**How can I effectively retrieve these numbers from the Python script ?**

Here is **loop.py**:

```
#!/usr/bin/python                                                        
import random

data = 200

def getData():
    return (data);

def main():
    while (42):
        global data
        data = random.randint(1, 10)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Here is **TestClass.cpp**:

```
# include "TestClass.hh"

TestClass::TestClass()
{
  _data = 200;
}

TestClass::~TestClass()
{}

void    TestClass::launchThread()
{
  PythonWrapper::callFuncFromModule("main", "loop");
}

void    TestClass::launchLoop()
{    
  std::thread t(&TestClass::launchThread, this);

  while (42)
    {
      _data = PythonWrapper::callFuncFromModule("getData", "loop");
      _mtx.lock();
      if (_data < 200)
          std::cout << "Data : " << _data << std::endl;
      _mtx.unlock();
    }
  t.join();
}
```

**TestClass.hh**:

```
#ifndef TEST_CLASS_HH
# define TEST_CLASS_HH

#include "PythonWrapper.hh"

#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <iostream>

class TestClass
{
public:
  TestClass();
  ~TestClass();
  void  launchLoop();

private:
  void  launchThread();

  int           _data;
  std::mutex    _mtx;
};

#endif /* TEST_CLASS_HH */
```

And here is my **PythonWrapper.cpp**:

```
#include "PythonWrapper.hh"

PyObject        *PythonWrapper::importModule(const std::string &filename)
{
  PyObject      *moduleName;
  PyObject      *module;

  moduleName = PyUnicode_FromString(filename.c_str());
  module = PyImport_Import(moduleName);
  Py_DECREF(moduleName);

  return (module);
}


int             PythonWrapper::callFuncFromModule(const std::string &funcName, const std::string &moduleName)
{
  PyObject      *func;
  PyObject      *args;
  PyObject      *retValue;
  PyObject      *module;
  int           ret;

  setenv("PYTHONPATH", ".", 1);
  Py_Initialize();

  module = importModule(moduleName);

  func = PyObject_GetAttrString(module, funcName.c_str());
  args = PyTuple_New(0);

  retValue = PyObject_CallObject(func, args);
  Py_DECREF(args);
  Py_DECREF(retValue);
  ret = PyLong_AsSize_t(retValue);

  Py_Finalize();

  return (ret);
}
```

**PythonWrapper.hh**

```
#ifndef PYTHONWRAPPER_HH_
# define PYTHONWRAPPER_HH_

# include <Python.h>
# include <iostream>
# include <string>

class PythonWrapper
{
public:
  static int    callFuncFromModule(const std::string &, const std::string &);

private:
  static PyObject      *importModule(const std::string &);
};

#endif /* PYTHONWRAPPER_HH_ */
```

And **main.cpp**:

```
int     main()
{
  TestClass test;
  test.launchLoop();
  return (0);
}
```

Here is the output of the program:

`segmentation fault (core dumped)`

I would like to avoid solutions using Boost.python or others if possible.

Best regards.

Comment: Could you minimise you code a bit?  Most users will just skip this because it's too long

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], minimal being the keyword here.

Comment: @Simon I edited my post but I don't think I can reduce it more

Comment: I don't think loop.py is necessary for a start

Comment: @Simon I removed it. But I thought it was necessary to be a complete example

Comment: My bad you should probably keep it.  I won't advise anymore.  Perhaps someone with more experience will be able to advise better than me.